# Making a regex that can find two words where the order can be reversed

Tags: regex

I'm working on a project that involves regular expressions and the issue I'm having is I need to make a regular expression that matches the following:

```
private int GoodYear(String in, int j){
private static int GoodYear(String in, int j){
private final int GoodYear(String in, int j){
private static final int GoodYear(String in, int j){
private final static int goodYear(String in, int j){
```

I've already made this:

```
^\s*(public\s+|private\s+|protected\s+)?(static\s+)?(final\s+)?(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*\((.*)\)\s*\{
```

It matches the first four but not the last one. How can I fix my regex so it will read "static" and "final" in either order?

any and all help is much appreciated!

-chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following pattern:

```
private\s*?(((final\s*?static)|(static\s*?final))|(final)|(static))?\s*?int\s*?goodyear\(.*?\){
```

The pattern includes `((final\s*?static)|(static\s*?final))` which allows you to match "final static" or "static final".

https://regex101.com/r/YVd4hU/1

Answer (score 0):

To match in either order, use
`((?:static(?:\s+final)?|final(?:\s+static)?)\s+)?`